# How to pass JavaScript variable into a PHP function parameter?

Tags: javascript, php, variables, twilio

I am trying to get a response from a Twilio API where I am facing complexity.
I have a javascript variable called `sid` which is containing a string value.

```
var sid = value['sid']; // 'CA519c6aefde211131f2f44370d67607d4'
```

Now I need to call this variable into a PHP function as a parameter.

```
<?php echo $twilio->check_disputed($parameter) ?>
```

So, the `$parameter` is coming from the Javascript `var sid`.

I want to place the javascript variable as the parameter.

Thanks <3

Comment: you need to send an HTTP request ( ajax most likely ) to your PHP script ( not shown!! ) and process that request with PHP.

Comment: Yes, because your JavaScript is running on the _client_ and PHP on the _server_.

Comment: if for any reason you don't want  to post  anything you can use this example:     (file=index.php )      <?php !empty($_REQUEST['parameter'])and print($_REQUEST['parameter']) and exit();?><!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>yooopy</title></head>
<body><script>let parameter=22;document.body.innerHTML +='<embed type="text/html" src="index.php?parameter='+parameter+'" width="250" height="200">';</script></body></html>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a very simple form/example you simply need to send an http request ( here done using the Fetch api ) to your PHP script and intercept that request. The following sends a POST request with a single parameter `sid` which is then passed to the Twilio method as per your requirement.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST['sid'] ) ){
        $sid=$_POST['sid'];
        exit( $twilio->check_disputed( $sid ) );
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Your page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Do lots of things...</h1>
        
        <script>
            /*
                do whatever it is you do to create your variable sid
                - here it is explicitly declared rather than derived.
            */
            const sid='CA519c6aefde211131f2f44370d67607d4';
            
            let fd=new FormData();
                fd.set('sid',sid);
                
            fetch( location.href, { method:'post', body:fd } )
                .then(r=>r.text())
                .then(data=>{
                    alert(data)
                })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Asynchronious request to achive that.
first import your jquery library

```
  var actual_url = "yourDomain/data=" + data_you_want_to_pass;
  $.ajax({
            url: actual_url,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'text', // added data type
            success: function(res) {
                //log if you have any response
                console.log(res);
            }
        });
```

now you can recieve the data on your php file using GET method.